# How to normalize a table to BCNF form

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, database-schema

I am trying to understand how to normalize a relation into BCNF form.
I know what is the definition of BCNF, and I know that in order to normalize it I need to eliminate every `D -> X` where `D` isn't part of a key candidate.
And to create a new tables of `(D,X)` and `(S,X)`.

I also read this threads:

1. [Normalisation into BCNF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286510/normalisation-into-bcnf)
2. [BCNF Decomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368271/bcnf-decomposition)
3. [Difference between 3NF and BCNF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437957/difference-between-3nf-and-bcnf-in-simple-terms-must-be-able-to-explain-to-an-8)

But the problem I am facing is how to use the algorithm when X is part of the super key.
I will explain:

Assume we have this relation:

```
R = (a,b,c,d,e)
FD = { {a,b}->{c} , {a,b}->{d} , {a,b}->{e} , {d}->{b} }
```

Obviously, the only super key is `(a,b)`. And clearly, `d` isn't a key candidate.

`d->b` violating the BCNF but we can't just take `b` out of the table since it is part of the super key.

So my question is: in this case, how can we normalize this relation into BCNF form?

Comment: I assume F is supposed to represent the functional dependencies, but I can't tell what the FDs actually are — the notation is ambiguous.  Maybe you mean `{a,b}⟶c; {a,b}⟶d; {a,b}⟶e; d⟶b`? where I've not used set `{}` around singleton sets.  Please clarify the set of FDs.

Comment: Yes, by `f` I ment `FD`. I edited, thank you. About the notation, I an following what I have saw so far at many places.

Comment: Yes, I ment to the FD you wrote. Edited that as well.

Comment: IIRC, there are sets of FDs that cannot be reduced to BCNF; this may be one such.  Meditate on the two relations R1 = (a,b,c,e) and R2 = (a,b,d).  I'm not at all sure that's a correct BCNF schema; the d⟶b FD is a pain.

Comment: *"Obviously, the only super key is (a,b)."* AD?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' Now it's more confusing..If `AD` is a super key, then this relation is in BCNF (since all FD are key candidate) but it is not even in 3NF since there is a transitive dependency on the key (AD is a key and we get C,E from D->B , A,B->E). But BNCF supposed to be stricter than 3NF. What am I missing?

Comment: *"If AD is a super key, then this relation is in BCNF (since all FD are key candidate)"* No, it would be in BCNF if every arrow in every FD were an arrow *out* of a candidate key. In the FD D->B you have an arrow that's *not* out of a candidate key.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' You right. It needs to be a candidate key, not a **part of** candidate key. But we came back to the original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answearing my own question (with the great help of Jonathan Leffler):

This relation should be normalize into:

```
R1 = (a,b,c,e). super-key is (a,b).
R2 = (b,d). super-key is (d).
```

I.e. every time a scheme `S` have a FD `D->X` who violating the BCNF:

If `D` isn't part of the key the new tables are `(D,X)` and `(S,X)`.
If `D` **is** part of the key the new tables are `(D,X)` and `(S,D)`.
If both `D` and `X` are part of the key then the relation can not normalize into BCNF from.

Comment: I don't think so. What happened to AB->D?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' BCNF does NOT necessarily keep the original functional dependencies.

Comment: I know. But it's not clear whether you think R1 and R2 are a BCNF decomposition of R. (Both *D* and *X* are part of a candidate key.)